# How to get a WebView app in the App Store?

Tags: ios, web-applications, webview, app-store

Hi I have develloped a webapp, and an 'android app' which is basically a WebView of the webapp. But now I wanna make an iOS version of the webapp which will be available in the appstore. Unfortunately another post suggests that it won't work with just a WebView because of Apple's guidelines. Does anyone have an idea on how to get it in the App Store without having to devellop a native app for iOS?

Comment: You can't put an app in the store that is just a view of a simple web site. If The underlying webapp  has significant functionality then it may be suitable, but you need some native code to run on the device to present the web app. Only native code apps can be submitted. The source code doesn't have to be Swift or Objective C. There are tools that allow you code in HTML/CSS/JS and compile that to a native app

Comment: You can try to do what you did on Android, by creating a "native" iOS app that is simply a UIWebView set to load your webapp, but it will still require you to sign up for an Apple developer account, and the app will almost certainly be rejected by Apple.  Apple does not want the App Store populated with people's web sites.  An app must have substantial benefit above simply serving up a webview.  If not, why not just use Safari?

Comment: What would be the purpose of having such an app in the App Store?  Discoverability?  Monetization?

Comment: @wottle well, the target group is a bunch of drunk teenangers (it's for a german 16+ club). And it's impossible to let them go to a website or add a website to their homescreen. Whereas installing an app is way easier to achieve. So that's why I want a real official app in the App Store.

Comment: @Paulw11 Won't this mess up my back-end (I used Node.JS for the back-end)?

Comment: Maybe. I couldn't say. I can tell you that only compiled code apps can be distributed by the App Store, so you will need a native app that wraps, say, `WKWebView` with your site, but if your app doesn't do anything that couldn't be done with Safari it will be rejected.

Comment: Okay, but how can I easily make native, because I dont have any knowledge about Swift/ObjectiveC @Paulw11

Comment: There are alternatives; I have never used them, but you can code for iOS in JavaScript and C# using different frameworks.

Comment: But I will have to rebuild the entire app?

Comment: Creating a native app with a single SFSafariViewController would be minimal work.  There are many tutorials out there. The real work is trying to convince Apple that they should change their policies for an app aimed at young drinkers is the right decision.

Comment: hahaah well here in germany it is legal so i hope that isn't against their policies, but we'll see. But I'll look into a SFSafariViewController. Thx bro.

Comment: The policy isn't against drunk teenagers (as long a they are legal age), it's against publishing native apps that don't offer anything over a web app.  They can tell that your compiled app only has a single webview, and will likely reject it.  I doubt your app will be the one to change their mind.  But it's your time and $99.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Whether Apple agrees to distribute your application is entirely about the details of your agreement with them, and [not something we can really help with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) because [we're not Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Comment: @LeviVerkerk wondering if you somehow solved this issue for ios?